# vue router with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import about from './views/web/AboutPage.vue';
import support from './views/web/SupportPage.vue';
import iatiStanderd from './views/web/IatiStandard.vue';
import publishingChecklist from './views/web/PublishingChecklist.vue';
import { def } from '@vue/shared';

const routes = [
  
  
  {
    path: '/iati-standard',
    name: 'iatiStanderd',
    component: iatiStanderd,
  },
  {
    path: '/support',
    name: 'Support',
    component: support,
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});
export default router;
```

I have set up routes like this.

```
app.use(router);
```

and registered like thi in app.ts file

```
 <router-link to="/iati-standard">IATI STANDARD</router-link>
```

and tried to use route like this.
the url changes but desired component is not rendered. where did i go wrong?
I am using vue with laravel

Comment: [edit] and attach your  `app.js` and `App.vue` component code with your question

Answer (score 1):

you should use the name instead of the URL.

In your case:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'iatiStanderd'}"> ... </router-link>
```

And btw, take care for the name it is iatiStandard not iatiStanderd

Comment: this didnt solve the issue. but thankyou

Comment: Do you have something more precise in the console ?